# create a new column with adding current values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df as:
production_unit_id|defective_item|defective_item_count|items_produced_count|items_discarded_count

P108|rock|46|1|315

P108|scissor|47|3|309

P108|rock|27|6|315

P085|scissor|50|8|194

P774|scissor|23|146|21

P774|scissor|5|146|21

i want the output as:
production_unit_id|defective_item|defective_item_count|items_produced_count|items_discarded_count

P108|rock|73|7|630

P108|scissor|47|3|309

P085|scissor|50|8|194

P774|scissor|28|292|42

the 'defective_item' column should be grouped and 'defective_item_count' should be added corresponding to the same 'defective_item' .

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format properly.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you share your code?

Comment: Also, SO is not a free coding site. What have *you* tried?

Comment: It is dupe `df = df.groupby(['production_unit_id','defective_item']).sum()` :(

Comment: yeah i have tried i also tried to groupby on column but that does not give the desired ouput. Also i have just asked a part of my problem , not the full solution. I think SO is a platform to get help from around the world . @MadPhysicist